# MVC 3 display data from a controller in another

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, drop-down-menu

i have 2 controllers event and students,

i would like to display student name in events as a dropdownlist ?

student contain name and age

event should contain a dropdownlist of student name and date .

```
public class Student
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime DOB{ get; set; }
    public string Class { get; set; }
    public int grade { get; set; }
    public string teeth { get; set; }
    public string heart{ get; set; }
    public string eye{ get; set; }
    public string genitals { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: you have a property for genitals?!

What code have you tried so far?

Comment: its part of health menu for the doctor ,
my focus is on name and age.

Answer (score 0):

Create another class that provides you with a list of students - for example StudentProvider. Then edit your Events Model and add there a list of students. In your events controller initialize this list by a result from StudentProvider. Then display this list on your event's view.

This kind of a "provider" pattern will ensure separation of concerns and you don't have to worry about combining two controllers together.

Comment: i am new to mvc3 so if you can show me any kind of example i would be really grateful.

Answer (score 0):

If my guess is correct this is what you want to happen in your application.

First add the following in your "Event" Model.

```
public class Event
{
        public int StudentID {get; set;}
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> DropDownStudent { get; set; }
        public void GetStudents()
        {
            var list = studentcontext.Select(e => new { Value = (int)e.ID, Text = e.Name.ToString() }).ToList();
            DropDownStudent = new SelectList(list, "Value", "Text");
        }
}
```

Second instantiate your model in your controller and return it to your view.

```
public ActionResult SampleView()
{
    var model = new Event();
    model.GetStudents(); //call GetStudent method so the DropDownStudent object will be populated.
    return View(model);
}
```

And in your view use "Event" as your model and add an @Html.DropDownListFor like so.

```
@model ProjectName.Model.Event

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.StudentID, Model.DropDownStudent)

}
```

I hope this help.